# SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2013 Migration

Tags: sharepoint, migration, sharepoint-2013

I am working with a customer which have SharePoint 2013 dev, test and prod environments sitting in a datacentre. We are moving the datacentre which means their SharePoint 2013 needs to be moved as is. They have 1 heavly custom build application on top of SharePoint which needs to be moved. I need confirmation, process suggestion on the migration part.

I install SharePoint 2013 like for like in new environment. 
Option 1
I take backup for their databases and restore them on new SQL Server. Use Mount-SPContentDatabase to mount database and test if everything is working as expected

Option 2
Recreate web application, site collections, activate custom features, timer job and migrate content.

I personally think that option 1 is more applicable but need input and suggestions. Any road blockers or gotcha are also encouraged. 
Thanks for sharing your experience

Answer (score 0):

As its a same version migration it wont be much of an issue but go with option 1.
Re Creating the whole farm is so hard specially if you decide to deploy each and every component.
I've migrations to same version and these are the steps that i follow.

1. Create a checklist of all solutions and features (WSP etc).
2. The check list should have the same services that are running in the farm as well.
3. Install SharePoint in the new farm and update to the same version as the existing farm , having same version will reduce a lot of
   problems.
4. Create the service applications just like the existing farm.
5. Restore the service application databases (MetaData, UserProfile etc)
6. Create the web application and restore the content database
7. Deploy the custom solutions
8. Confirm that everything in your checklist is deployed and working fine
9. Fix errors if there are any

This is the flow that i follow and so far i've been successful.
Good Luck